# PrintWriter is printing only the first line in text file

Tags: java, printwriter

The closing of PrintWriter is placed in the finally block, so logically it should write all the existing line in the text file as the code below suggests,

```
     public boolean updatecentre(String row, int cuid) throws IOException
{
    boolean updated = false;
    int dbcuid;
    String dbcname, dbcentre, dba1, dba2, dba3, vac1, dose1, vac2, dose2, vac3, dose3, dbstr;
    
    File F1 = new File("Centre.txt");
    File Ftc1 = new File("Temp.txt");
    FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(Ftc1, true);
    BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
    PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(bw1);
    Scanner Sc1 = new Scanner(F1);
    Sc1.useDelimiter("[/\n]");
    try
    {
        while(Sc1.hasNext())
        {
            dbcuid = Sc1.nextInt();
            dbcname = Sc1.next();
            dba1 = Sc1.next();
            dba2 = Sc1.next();
            dba3 = Sc1.next();
            vac1 = Sc1.next();
            dose1 = Sc1.next();
            vac2 = Sc1.next();
            dose2 = Sc1.next();
            vac3 = Sc1.next();
            dose3 = Sc1.next();
            dbstr = dbcuid+"/"+dbcname+"/"+dba1+"/"+dba2+"/"+dba3+"/"+vac1+"/"+dose1+"/"+vac2+"/"+dose2+"/"+vac3+"/"+dose3;
            if(dbcuid == cuid)
            {
                pw1.print(row +"\n");
                updated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pw1.print(dbstr+"\n");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        
    }
    finally
    {
        Sc1.close();
        pw1.flush();
        pw1.close();
        bw1.close();
        fw1.close();
        F1.delete();
        File dump = new File("Centre.txt");
        Ftc1.renameTo(dump);  
    }
    return updated;
}
```

But what it does now is that it prints just the first line, the line after it are not printed upon execution, so what is the problem here? It was working fine yesterday, but all of the sudden this issue started to appear.

Content in text file:

```
1/Axiata Arena Bukit Jalil/L2-E-10, Enterprise 4,/Technology Park Malaysia, Bukit Jalil,/57000, Kuala Lumpur/Pfizer-BioNTech/100/CoronaVac/50/AstraZeneca/25
2/Titiwangsa Stadium/Jalan Tembeling,/Titiwangsa,/53200, Kuala Lumpur/Pfizer-BioNTech/100/CoronaVac/50/AstraZeneca/25
3/Kompleks Sukan Pandamaran Klang/Padamaran,/Port Klang,/42000, Selangor/Pfizer-BioNTech/100/CoronaVac/50/AstraZeneca/25
4/KPL Ampang Puteri Hospital/1, Jalan Mamanda 9,/Taman Dato Ahmad Razali,/68000 Ampang, Selangor/Pfizer-BioNTech/100/CoronaVac/50/AstraZeneca/25
5/Mines Convention Centre/MIECC, Jalan Dulang,/Mines Wellness City, Seri Kembangan,/43300, Selangor/Pfizer-BioNTech/100/CoronaVac/50/AstraZeneca/25
```

Comment: Do you checked with the debugger whether you go through the while loop more than one time?

Comment: try to print anything in the catch block just to be sure that there are no Exceptions : 
           catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: That delimiter seems a bit fishy. What is the format of your file?

Comment: @Renis1235 I have updated the post and included the text file.

Comment: @OussamaZAGHDOUD It says java.util.InputMismatchException, and it seems like the line `dbcuid = Sc1.nextInt();` is not getting a number from the text file, but the first value in each row is a number

Comment: @Syramid you can use instead of this line :  if(Sc1.hasNextInt()) { dbcuid = Sc1.nextInt(); }

Comment: @OussamaZAGHDOUD Thank you very much for the suggestion. It turns out that the structure of the text file is the problem, everything works fine now after I have made a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your code with your file worked for me. But the error that you receive signals that you are not reading an integer with `scanner.nextInt()`.

I would test your full file with this snippet below. Just to check where does the parsing fail. And fix that problem.

```java
String dbcuidStr = sc.next();

try
{
    System.out.println("This is the ID: " + dbcuidStr);
    dbcuid = Integer.parseInt(dbcuidStr);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(dbcuidStr + " could not be parsed to an integer");
    
}
```

And you could always use `Scanner` functions such as `.hasNextInt()`.